# Logging from my Java EE Application

Tags: log4j, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, slf4j

I have a big Problem with my Logging. I have a the following strucure of my project:

> - MyApplication
>
>   - ear
>   - ejb
>   - com.test.util (src/main/java)
>
>     - Resources.java (Produce the Logger Instance)
>     - Some Classe which use the Logger with @Inject
>   - log4j.xml (src/main/resources)
>   - web

Here's my Resources.java:

```
import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
public class Resources {
   @Produces
   @PersistenceContext
   private EntityManager em;
   @Produces
   public Logger produceLog(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
      return LoggerFactory.getLogger(injectionPoint.getMember().getDeclaringClass().getName());
   }
}
```

And here is my log4j.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN"
    "http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/xml/doc-files/log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="org.apache.log4j.AsyncAppender">
        <!-- <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> -->
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-d: %-5p [%8c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="${jboss.server.home.dir}/log/emember.log" />
        <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10000KB" />
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="5" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-d: %-5p [%8c] - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <category name="org.hibernate.type">
        <priority value="trace" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate.SQL">
        <priority value="debug" />
    </category>

    <category name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder">
        <priority value="trace" />
    </category>

    <category name="ch.test">
        <priority value="debug" />
    </category>

    <root>
        <priority value="INFO" />
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Whe i use my Unit-Test it work's fine, but when i deplay the ear-File then it doesn't use my log4j.xml. I use a JBoss AS 7 Application Server. And yes i've read all the tutorials with this title, but it doesn't work for me.
Can someone help me with this Problem?

Comment: What version of JBoss AS 7? Some versions will pick up the log4j.xml and configure the log4j logmanager, others will not.

Comment: i use the jboss 7.1.1 standalone version

Answer (score 2):

You want to bootstrap SLF4j to be picked up by your EAR application as early as possible. Given you are using JBoss AS 7 as a Java EE 6 implementation, you can use EJB 3.1 singletons as follows:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class BootstrapLogging {

    @PostConstruct
    public void doUponConstruction() {
        URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("log4j.xml");
        DOMConfigurator.configure(url);
    }
}
```

Another Qualifier to guarantee type safety to avoid possible ambiguity with JBoss Logger bean:

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, PARAMETER, TYPE})
public @interface SLF4jLogger {
}
```

Finally, you can inject the Logger using the following snippet:

```
    @Inject @SLF4jLogger
    private Logger LOG;
```

Please add a comment, in case you have a further inquiry. I will reply as soon as I can.

Comment: I've tested the first method and now it creates the log-File but it's still empty and all logging-informations go to the server log

Comment: Please try either LOG.warn() or LOG.info() ONLY, and let me know if you see your messages in the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason you want to deploy your log4j.xml? This makes it hard to configure the logging at runtime. I would configure the logging in standalone.xml. If you do this to get application-specific logging, I would configure logging-profiles (>7.1/EAP6.1)

Comment: the reason was, that my application is server-independ.

Answer (score 0):

This *might* work if you [exclude](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/How+To#HowTo-HowdoIuselog4j.propertiesorlog4j.xmlinsteadofusingtheloggingsubsystemconfiguration%3F) the servers logging dependencies and include in your deployment. You would need log4j, slf4j-api and the bindings for slf4j to log4j. I can't recall exactly how the slf4j static bindings work which if it doesn't work would be where the issue likely is.

For the exclusions in your `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` you'd need to exclude the modules `org.slf4j`, `org.apache.log4j` and possible `org.apache.commons.logging`.

IMO though logging should be configured on the server and not within a deployment. When configured within a deployment you lose things like runtime changes to the logging configuration. Say you want to enable debug logging for a specific category. If you use the server logging it will like work with a command/operation of some sort. If you use a configuration within your deployment you'd likely have to redeploy your application.